# Pin Payments API - "Authentication failed because remote party has closed the transport stream"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, ssl, payment-gateway

I'm trying to add payments to my web site using the Pin Payments payment gateway.  My site is being developed in MVC and I'm using the PinPayments C# library that is suggested in the API documentation.

I read that the api documentation that stated is only accepts Secure connections.  So i enabled SSL in my solution. I then made sure that the Self signed certificate that IIS Express generates is added to my trusted certs. It worked once after i trusted the Certificate.  But since then it has continued to fail. And it alternates between the following error messages.  Without me making any changes to the code.

An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

and

Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

Here is my code that makes the request.  The card and charge are build without error and it then goes to run the line ChargeResponse response = ps.Charge(charge);.  It then jumps to the pinpayments library requester code (Below).

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreditCard (CreditCardPayment model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // get application
        Application application = db.Applications.Find(model.ApplicationdId);

        if (application != null)
        {
            PinService ps = new PinService(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Secret_API"]);

            var card = new Card();
            card.CardNumber = model.Number;
            card.CVC = model.Cvn;
            card.ExpiryMonth = model.ExpiryMonth;
            card.ExpiryYear = model.ExpiryYear;
            card.Name = model.Name;
            card.Address1 = model.AddressLine1;
            card.City = model.City;
            card.Country = model.Country;

            var charge = new PostCharge();
            charge.Description = "Visa Application " + application.Destination;
            charge.Amount = Convert.ToInt64(application.Total) * 100;  // Pin payments requires the value in cents
            charge.Card = card;
            charge.Currency = application.CurrencyCode;
            charge.Email = application.Customer.Email;
            charge.IPAddress = "127:0:0:1"; //Request.UserHostAddress; 

            ChargeResponse response = ps.Charge(charge);

            if (response.Charge != null && response.Charge.Success)
            {
                // Update application with payment details.
            }
            else
            {
                // Do error stuff
            }
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Here is the code that is in the Pin Payments Library that the request fails on.  It goes to run the first line but then jumps to the var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream(); line with the error message.

```
private static WebRequest GetWebRequest(string url, string method, string postData)
{
    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = method;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.UserAgent = "C# API Wrapper v001";

    string apiKey = PinPaymentsConfig.GetApiKey();
    request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(apiKey + ":"));

    if (postData != "")
    {
        var paramBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentLength = paramBytes.Length;

        var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(paramBytes, 0, paramBytes.Length);
    }
    return request;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pin Payments dropped support of TLS 1.0 on their test API, and will be dropping it on their live API in Jan 2017. Can you confirm you're connecting via TLS 1.1 or above?

Please note, TLS 1.1 and 1.2 support was only added in .NET 4.5.

Feel free to reach out to us at support@pin.net.au for further support.

Comment: Thanks Pin Payments.  This was the issue.  I had to rebuild the library as .net 4.5 and forced the GetWebRequest method to use TLS 1.2